# ASP MVC Areas for themes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, themes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm currently searching for a solution where a user could select a theme AND a layout based on his preferences.

Let's say I have a website that offers 2 themes: yellow and green.

These two have 2 different layouts: 2 columns and 3 columns layout and some partial views will be structured differently and have different functional aspects.

The best way I thought was to use Areas but, what I don't want is the URL structure to change at all. I would use a variable that sets the area behind the scenes when the action is executed.

For instance, I'm setting my layout to 3 columns and use the green theme.
I would use the 3Cols area with it's specific views but the controller implements the same exact code as the 2Cols layout so, I don't want to duplicate the controller.

So, a recap of what I'm trying to achieve is this:

- Use Areas to swith layouts and themes
- Use a single controller for each layouts
- Have the same urls independantly from the selected layout

Any thoughts/suggestions on that?

Thank you!

Comment: By using an area, the url structure of your site will change. No two areas can answer for the same request, thats part of the routing. While it would be possible to create some base classes to capture requests and inject an area in to the route based on the users selected theme. I've created my own view engine and plugin system for a multi-tennant application that allows you to override a controller and/or view for a specific client but thats way more complicated than what you need. Perhaps you should look at creating your own View Engine to over-ride the search locations for your views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get what I was looking for working and I think it's very simple!

I've created a BaseController class:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] = CurrentLayout;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public string CurrentLayout
    {
        get
        {
            //Set a default layout if no layout is specified
            if(Session["CurrentLayout"]==null)
                Session["CurrentLayout"] = "Layout1";
            return Session["CurrentLayout"].ToString();
        }

        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                throw new NullReferenceException("CurrentLayout");
            CurrentLayout = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, at the start of a session, I read the user's profile and put its selected layout in the session variable the BaseController is reading.

Nothing else is required!

Hope this helps others.

Thanks!